# Split an array based on value

Tags: powershell

This is my first question here, so sorry if I make any mistakes posting this.

I'm trying to split an array based on its values. Basically I want to create two arrays whose values are as close to the average as possible. I managed to do this with this code:

```
function Sum($v) {
    [Linq.Enumerable]::Sum([int64[]]$v)
}

$arr = 0..9 | % {get-random -min 1 -max 10}
"ARRAY:" + $arr
"SUM: " + (sum $arr)
"AVG: " + (sum $arr)/2

# start of the code that matters
$wavg = (sum $arr)/2
foreach ($i in (0..($arr.Count-1))) {
    $wavg -= $arr[$i]
    if ($wavg -le 0) {
        $i-=(-$wavg -gt $arr[$i]/2);break
    }
}

"SPLIT INDEX: " + $i
"ARR1: " + $arr[0..$i] + " (" + $(sum $arr[0..$i]) + ")"
"ARR2: " + $arr[($i+1)..$arr.Count] + " (" + $(sum $arr[($i+1)..$arr.Count]) + ")"
```

The reason my `foreach` is structured this way is because in my actual code the values are in an index hash and are accessed as `$index[$arr[$i]]`.

This means that the resulting two arrays could be of unequal size (it would be easy if I could just split the array in half). Sample output of my code to demonstrate this:

```
ARRAY: 5 3 6 3 2 3 6 3 1 3
SUM: 35
AVG: 17.5
SPLIT INDEX: 3
ARR1: 5 3 6 3 (17)
ARR2: 2 3 6 3 1 3 (18)
```

The code works as is, but I feel it could be done in a more elegant and speedier way. Because I need to execute this code a few thousand times in my script I want it to be as fast as possible.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear - "I want to create two arrays whose values are as close to the average as possible" - does that mean you want to have an equal number of items in the two resulting arrays, but their sum as close to each others as possible? Or do your want two arrays of potential unequal size with an average as close to each other as possible? Could you perhaps supply an example of input values and desired output?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I wasn't clear. I want to split the array so that the sum of each new array is as close to the average of the old array as possible. This means the size of new arrays could be unequal. example output of my code:

ARRAY:5 3 6 3 2 3 6 3 1 3
SUM: 35
AVG: 17.5
SPLIT INDEX: 3
ARR1: 5 3 6 3 (17)
ARR2: 2 3 6 3 1 3 (18)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for critique of working code belong on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).